# Creating JSON objects in Typescript

Tags: json, typescript, lodash

How to create/save an array of JSON objects only when there is a new item?
The problem I am having is:

1. How can I create/save JSON objects directly or do I have to have a corresponding class object created?
2. What Is the best way to check if particular item exists or not?

Comment: Your question is not clear as-is. Perhaps you could show us some code to better illustrate the question here?

Comment: You don't really need to do anything special, just use `any`: https://jsfiddle.net/ywp4n8dy/1

Comment: sharing a js example of what you want to create might help. :)

Comment: @Corey Ogburn. This works for me. can we do the same with loadash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the json in variables of class `any` but usually you will want to have some typing on these object so what I usually do is having a fromJson static method on my model classes that will instantiate an object from a json like that:

```
class User {

    public firstname: string;
    public lastname: string;
    public age: number;

    constructor() {
    }

    public static fromJson(userJson: any): User {
        var user = new User();

        this.firstname = userJson.firstname;
        this.lastname = userJson.lastname;
        this.age = userJson.age;

        return user;
    }
}
```

If one of your properties is a class you can also have a from json on it and embed it in the from json like that:

```
class User {

    public firstname: string;
    public lastname: string;
    public status: Status;

    constructor() {
    }

    public static fromJson(userJson: any): User {
        var user = new User();

        this.firstname = userJson.firstname;
        this.lastname = userJson.lastname;
        this.status = Status.fromJson(userJson.status);

        return user;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps